# How to build a binary tree of unique_ptrs working around std::move?

Tags: c++, tree, unique-ptr

I am currently trying to create a binary tree, each node of which contains a unique_ptr pointing to some other node in the tree. My question is one about design: I am not entirely sure how to write a recursive function that would build a tree like this without calling move on the pointers contained in the nodes in order to pass them as parameters to the next recursive function call.

I have a function that looks something like this:

```
void MParser::parseExpression(unique_ptr<Symbol>& parent, string expression){

    Scope mainScope = findMainScope(expression);
    unique_ptr<Symbol> child;
    
    if (mainScope.type == ScopeType::Atomic){

        child = buildAtom(expression);
        parent->appendChild(child);
        return;

    }else{

        child = buildOperation(mainScope.type);
        parent->appendChild(child);

        vector<string> operands = separateOperands(mainScope, expression);

        parseExpression(child, operands[0]);
        parseExpression(child operands[1]);
    }  
}
```

The problem is, my appendChild() function involves a std::vector.push_back(), which requires the child passed in to be moved with std::move(). This is ok for now, the child node has been pushed into the tree at the right position. However, the child variable within this function is now a nullptr, and when I try to pass it into the next function call I get undesired behaviour.

The other problem is that if I implement a getter method to retrieve the child node from the tree to bring it back into the scope of the function, it will also have to be moved and so its parent node in the tree will point to a nullptr.

I would prefer not to use a shared_ptr because there isnt really any shared ownership, and it will slow down the function substantially.

Im sure this is a design problem that im not thinking about correctly. Any help how I might resolve this is appreciated.

Comment: Have `appendChild` return a reference to the post-appended (i.e. the moved-to) unique pointer. Then use that for the recursions into `parseExpression`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The problem is, my `appendChild()` function involves a `std::vector.push_back()`, which requires the child passed in to be moved with `std::move()`. This is ok for now, the child node has been pushed into the tree at the right position. However, the child variable within this function is now a nullptr, and when I try to pass it into the next function call I get undesired behaviour.

When using move semantics you need to make sure you're done accessing the object being moved. In this case simply reordering the statements should do the trick. Furthermore I'd recommend going with `std::vector::emplace_back` to call the move constructor directly without using default constructor + move assignment.

```
}else{

    child = buildOperation(mainScope.type);

    vector<string> operands = separateOperands(mainScope, expression);

    parseExpression(child, operands[0]);
    parseExpression(child operands[1]);

    parent->appendChild(child);

}
```

Alternatively you could have `appendChild` return a const reference to the newly constructed node; just make sure to never add more children while using the reference.

```
}else{

    child = buildOperation(mainScope.type);

    const std::unique_ptr<Symbol>& currentChildHolder = parent->appendChild(child);

    vector<string> operands = separateOperands(mainScope, expression);

    parseExpression(currentChildHolder, operands[0]);
    parseExpression(currentChildHolder, operands[1]);
}
```

---

> The other problem is that if I implement a getter method to retrieve the child node from the tree to bring it back into the scope of the function, it will also have to be moved and so its parent node in the tree will point to a nullptr.

Return a const reference. This allows accessing the node without allocating a new object, e.g.:

```
const std::unique_ptr<Symbol>& ParentSymbol::GetChild(size_t index)
{
    return m_children[index];
}
```

Again note that this reference may become unusable if the list of children is modified in length, so you may want to "extract" the info from the `unique_ptr` object using `std::unique_ptr::get`. Alternatively you could return a non-smart pointer directly.